# Using Legacy Outer Join Syntax

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, outer-join

I need to make a change in a legacy SQL System (on the servers, its still on 2008R2 and 2000 Compatibility mode). My local DB is SQL 2012 - so the lowest compat mode I can get to is 2005.

Unfortunately there are a bunch of Procs using the Legacy ([Pre-SQL92](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213228%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)) join syntax - i.e. `*=` and `=*`. It's beyond the scope of my current work to fix this (although I have flagged it up the chain as a technical debt). Is there a way to enable this syntax in SQL 2012 for this particular DB?

Comment: No this isn't possible. This syntax has been deprecated since SQL Server 2005. Time to pay back some of this technical debt.